# Unable to install Airflow even after setting SLUGIFY_USES_TEXT_UNIDECODE and AIRFLOW_GPL_UNIDECODE

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, airflow

I am installing `airflow` via command:
`python3 setup.py install`. It takes in the requirements file, `requirements/athena.txt` which is:

> apache-airflow[celery,postgres,hive,password,crypto]==1.10.1

I got an error:

```
RuntimeError: By default one of Airflow's dependencies installs a GPL dependency (unidecode). To avoid this dependency set SLUGIFY_USES_TEXT_UNIDECODE=yes in your environment when you install or upgrade Airflow. To force installing the GPL version set AIRFLOW_GPL_UNIDECODE
```

To remove this error, I set `export SLUGIFY_USES_TEXT_UNIDECODE=yes` and `export AIRFLOW_GPL_UNIDECODE=yes`. However, running the command `python3 setup.py install` still gives the same error, nothing changed. To check env variables:

```
➜  athena-py git:(pyspark-DataFrameStatFunctions) echo $SLUGIFY_USES_TEXT_UNIDECODE
yes
➜  athena-py git:(pyspark-DataFrameStatFunctions) echo $AIRFLOW_GPL_UNIDECODE
yes
```

Comment: python3 is the version

Comment: which python version ? 3.5 or 3.7?

Comment: Python 3.7.2 is the exact version

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Airflow is not officially supporting python3.7 yet.

[image]

I think `pip` might not be picking up your environment variables. You can try the following command on your shell to make sure it picks up the options you are providing.

````
AIRFLOW_GPL_UNIDECODE=yes pip3 install "apache-airflow[celery,postgres,hive,password,crypto]==1.10.1"```
````

Comment: I created a virtualenv(just an fyi). It worked! Though, we should look into why env variables weren't picked up. Any idea?